# I want to make the delete all button appear only when there is an element in the list of my to do list app

Tags: javascript, button

I have made a to do list app, everything is working but if i delete all the element present in the list manually the delete all button will still appear on the screen obviously. I can't seem to be able to find a soultion...
Maybe i should make an array of every li element that gets created but i don't really know how go about that...

```
const input = document.querySelector("#input");
const button = document.querySelector("#btn");
const list = document.getElementById("list");
const deleteAllButton = document.getElementById("deleteall")

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    let inputvalue = input.value;
    
    

    if (!inputvalue) {
      alert("Inserisci un task");
    } else {
      let task = document.createElement("li");
      let taskinput = document.createElement("input");
      taskinput.disabled= true;
      taskinput.value = inputvalue;
    

      list.appendChild(task)
      task.appendChild(taskinput)
      input.value = ''
      
      let editButton = document.createElement("button");
      let editText = document.createTextNode("Edit")
      editButton.type = "button"
      editButton.id ="edit"
      editButton.appendChild(editText)
      task.appendChild(editButton)

      let deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
      let deleteText = document.createTextNode("Delete")
      deleteButton.type = "button"
      deleteButton.id= "delete"
      deleteButton.appendChild(deleteText)
      task.appendChild(deleteButton)

      
      deleteAllButton.style.display= "block";
  
      deleteAllButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        deleteAllButton.style.display= "none"
        list.innerHTML = '';


    })
  

     

      editButton.addEventListener("click", () =>{
         taskinput.disabled = false
         editButton.style.display= "none"
         deleteButton.style.display= "none"


         let saveButton = document.createElement("button");
         let saveText = document.createTextNode("Save")
         saveButton.type = "button"
         saveButton.id ="save"
         saveButton.appendChild(saveText)
         task.appendChild(saveButton)  
        
        saveButton.addEventListener("click", () => {

            console.log(taskinput.value)

            if(!taskinput.value){
                alert("Input field is empty")
            }else{
            taskinput.disabled = true;
            editButton.style.display= "block"
            deleteButton.style.display= "block"
            saveButton.remove()
            }
        

        })
    })

    deleteButton.addEventListener ('click', ()=>{
        
      
            task.remove()
        console.log(task)
        
    })

    }

  

    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the length of the list (list.childNodes) before displaying the delete all button. If the length of the list is 0, then you can hide the delete all button.

```
//...
list.appendChild(task)
  //...
  
  if (list.childNodes.length > 0) {
    deleteAllButton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    deleteAllButton.style.display = "none";
  }
  
  deleteAllButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    deleteAllButton.style.display= "none"
    list.innerHTML = '';
  })
//...
deleteButton.addEventListener ('click', ()=>{
  task.remove()
  if (list.childNodes.length === 0) {
    deleteAllButton.style.display = "none";
  }
})
//...
```

Comment: Thnak you very much, it worked!

Comment: I made some stylistic changes and then the delete button didn't work when i deleted the list items one by one, i console logged list.chilsNodes and there was a textnode, i deleted the changes but it still didn't work, then out of nowhere it worked again and when console logging list.childNodes there wasn't any textNoded, even though i didn't made any changes.  i don't understand where this textnode is coming from, i thought it was created when i left the input empty and tried to create a list item, but it wasn't that. what am i missing?

Comment: I resolved using children instead of childnodes, but still curious, because i want to understand. Thank you again for your help btw!